# How do I remove the blue edge scroll lines of a listview?

Tags: java, android, listview

I need help to find the correct command, on android, to remove the blue edge lines of a scrollable listview.

As an example, here it is the image related:

[image]

unfortunately, I can't find any example on this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called overscroll and can be disabled with [`.setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_NEVER)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setOverScrollMode%28int%29)

Comment: hello this code work for Galaxy s2 ,but not worked for Galaxy Tab GT-P1000. kindly req to post answer.