# Style for scroll limit in Android 4.2.x

Tags: android, styles, scroll, themes

I'm trying to create a custom theme for my android app. I'm testing my application on two different devices HTC One X (4.1) and Google Nexus 4 (4.2). Now I got an issue for theming scrolling/swiping behaviors for example in ViewPagers order ListViews. It's hard to explain, so I made a screenshot.

[image]

http://imageshack.us/a/img835/3572/blueshadow.jpg

Is it possible to remove order change that style that appears, when the scroll limit of a view is reached?
This does appear on the nexus 4, but not on the HTC One X.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Arcim - FYI you can embed images into your question. I've done this for you here, but in future you can click the "Image" button in the editor to do this.

Comment: Hi Raad, thanks a lot. I tried this too, but wasn't able due insufficient reputation :( (at least 10 needed to embed pictures).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
viewPager.setOverScrollMode(ViewPager.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
```

and

```
listView.setOverScrollMode(ListView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
```

sovled the issue.

Thanks to original answer: [Blue edge scroll lines of listview. Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967455/blue-edge-scroll-lines-of-listview-android)